# Generalized "softmax"

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I'm looking for a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $[0,1]^n$, similar to softmax in the sense that is satisfies these properties:

- $\sum_i f(x)_i = c$, where $c$ is a chosen constant (i.e., c=1 for "softmax")
- $0\leq f(x)_i \leq 1$
- $f$ is derivable w.r.t. the $x_i$s (w.r.t. $c$ is a bonus)

Does such a function exist?

Edit: after thinking about it, I guess it should also have these properties, or something close to it:

- $f(b) = b$ if $b=[1,...,1, 0, ...,0]$ where there are $c$ ones.
- $f(0) = [c/n, ..., c/n]$

I feel like I'm asking alot though.

Comment: Trivially, $c<1$ or $c > n$ will blow up your second constraint. For all other values of $c$, you can pick $f$ as a constant function ($f(x) = b$ where $\|b\|_1 = c$ and $b\in [0,1]^n$).

Comment: Well, your answer is correct. I think my question is a bit too vague, but I don't really know how to formulate the constraints I want.

Comment: If you want, you can think about it for a while and ask as a new question. As for this one, I can convert my comment to an answer or you can delete the question altogether if you wish.

Comment: I've edited my question, but should I ask a new one?

Comment: No, that's fine since you don't obsolete any existing answers. That's why I commented in the first place ;)